# AngularJS return the factory after posts array was populated

Tags: angularjs, factory-pattern

I have the following AngularJS factory where I consume my API data:

```
.factory('posts', function posts($http) {

    var posts = [];
    $http.get('/api').success(function(data) {
        posts = data;
    });

    /* === return this after $http is done === */

    return {
        get: function(offset, limit) {
            return posts.slice(offset, offset + limit);
        },

        total: function() {
            return posts.length;
        }
    }

});
```

My problem is that I need to return the get() just after the posts array is populated, when the `$http` request is done.

Can someone explain me how to achive this?
Return the factory methods just when the `$http.get()` is done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you must return the promsie.

```
.factory('posts', function posts($http,$q) {

var posts = [];


/* === return this after $http is done === */

return {
    get: function(offset, limit) {
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        if(posts.length==0){
           $http.get('/api').success(function(data) {
               posts = data;
               deferred.resolve(posts.slice(offset, offset + limit));
           });
         } else {
            deferred.resolve(posts.slice(offset, offset + limit));
         }
         return deferred.promise;            
    },
    total: function() {
        return posts.length;
    }
  }

});
```

Comment: Its not returning anything

Comment: in you controller user then function to get data,  posts.get(offset,limit).then(function(data){here is the data})l

Comment: But each time when Im calling I get the same results, the thing is that I need to populate the posts = [ // all posts ] and on get just send some parts of the array, how can I achive this?

Comment: i updat e my answer that the http call onli o the first time.